# unexpected token error jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

The following keeps throwing out an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` and I can't see what's wrong with it??

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($("a.burger-menu").is(":hidden") {
        $("nav a").show();
    }
});
```

Can anyone help?

Many Thanks

Comment: If you use firebug in the console you can see the error ;)
it helps a lot

Comment: Missing paren after ...(":hidden")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed the `if()` condition.Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($("a.burger-menu").is(":hidden")) {
        $("nav a").show(); //           ^ That was missing.
    }
});
```

Comment: Np. I usually add pointers like that in case of missing braces, semicolons, etc. Makes it easier to spot the difference. ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: yeah... i was afraid that OP do not confuse what i said with curly braces ending.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot guys...sitting here going crazy ha!